# How to migrate page versions from once CQ instance to another?

Tags: versioning, aem

I am working on Adobe CQ. I created 2-3 versions(1.2,1.2,1.3) for a particular page in my author instance. Now I tried to package my content page and installed it in another instance. I couldn't see the versions of the page which I installed in another instance.

Can anyone help me out doing this?? I want to migrate my content pages along with their versions from one CQ instance to another??

Answer (score 2):

We are in the same situation. You can extract prior version details using the packaging approach, but you will be precluded from reloading them in due to the new Oak security model. The next issue is that you would need to extract and transform the data, and then reinsert due to the node ID's potentially differing, especially if you are using partial data sets to extract.

Where we have gotten to, and are proving now, is to use the new migration tool to move content from instance to instance, which purportedly has a version extract tool. I will update details here when we get our results back.

---

UPDATE:

We have tested the CRX2OAK migration tool, and it indeed does move versions across. Using the tool, you can specify filters to only migrate a subset of content, which will then drag the version details across as well.

It seems this approach works quite well for both single tenancy and multi tenancy approaches as it used to using a package for content.

Unfortunately, it can't be used as a portable backup system, as it is an instance to instance solution. It does, however, work well for blue/green deployment strategies.

Comment: This is a good suggestion and my testing confirms this. However how about the fact that CRX2OAK recommends (if not requires) that the source aem is stopped before copying?

Comment: It can't be used whilst the system is running. This works if you have multi leg and can shut an author/publish pair down, or at least if you're on the cloud, take a snapshot instance and use that as your source.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Indeed that's what I'm doing. Btw in good aem style running crx2oak on a running system doesn't actually plain fail. It takes forever to complete and throws a few exception along the way.

Comment: Good to know if a patch has solved it. AEM 6.0 running SP2 busted out for us when the system was in use. The real concern was that it silently failed and only manifested when we started the new system, so if you're using it as a backup method, there's no guarantee that you've got anything.

Answer (score 1):

Versions are stored by path '/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage' in AEM.
To transfer pages with their versions just create a package with filters for content which you want to move and the version storage path as well, download package and install in other AEM.

Comment: Thank you Alexander.. But I tried in the way which you said earlier also but when I installed the package in other AEM. Under jcr:VersionStorage I couldn't find version nodes.. I can only see latest modified version of the page which is stored with some string value and jcr:rootVersion node under that

Comment: What version of AEM are you using ?

Comment: You can create a package which will store version info on a .content.xml file, but that content can't simply be installed on a different author because of https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/release-notes/deprecated-removed-features.html (Default ACLs section)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this question like me, here is the summarised answer:

You can use crx2oak utility available from link below to migrate pages and page version across instances:
https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/crx2oak/

This is a powerful utility with multiple uses (especially in upgrades) as documented in links below:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/upgrade/using-crx2oak.html
https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/migration.html

The source and destination repositories need to be offline while running this utility so best to plan ahead for this type of migration.

HTH

Comment: Does this work for AEM 6.3? We just migrated from 6.1 to 6.3 (NOT the in-place upgrade), so need to migrate the versions from 6.1 instance to 6.3.

Comment: It can work but you are better off using oak2oak becuase 6.1 is already on oak so crx2oak is superceded by oak2oak.